# "She noticed the change of (in?) her son" - choosing the right preposition

Tags: prepositions

Am I right to say such like this:

> She noticed the change **of** her son.

Is it different from the sentence:

> she noticed the change **in** her son?

Comment: **change of her son** sound something like this. Say there are two person named A and B, both are of her son's age. "A" is her son. If you say **change of her son**, it might mean now "B" is her son :-) (It might not be the exact idea, but I guess you got it) **Change in her son** is something like that. Her son was angry, and now he calmed down. That is **change in her son**.

Comment: You lost me @Man_From_India! :) I was thinking a chemistry olympiad question looking at that! Oh, I get it now!

Comment: @MARamezani Chemistry and English :-) nice combination :-)

Answer (score 1):

"The change **in** her son" would represent a change within her son, i.e a change in how he feels internally. "The change **of** her son" would mean that she noticed somebody has replaced her son.

Comment: Why was this downvoted?

Comment: *My* downvote is because idiomatically native speakers would almost always use the gerund noun form ***changing*** in the unlikely event that they intended your second meaning (and if for some reason they were unwilling to use a more "natural" noun such as *replacement, substitution*).

Comment: Well, speaking as a native British English speaker, reading that second statement and interpreting it the way I did is how I and most of the people I know would have.

Comment: I can see where you're coming from. But (1) it would require you to assume the statement came from a native speaker, otherwise it's obviously just a non-native speaker using the wrong preposition. And (2) even if we switch to a more credible context, I don't believe *any* native speaker would say, for example, *"I noticed the change of your son's car"* when they meant *"I see your son changed his car"*. On a *learners* site, your answer misleadingly imputes validity to an effectively "invalid" utterance.

Comment: X noticed the change in her son. is perfectly idiomatic. Gees. This answer is fine.